# json does not show the result

Tags: javascript, json

I have an html file with json request. I cannot make json show the result.
What's the mistake i have?

```
<p id="syno"></p>
```

That is where i should see the result
and below is the script for that

```
<script>
var apiUrl = 'http://words.bighugelabs.com/apisample.php?v=2&format=json';
$.ajax({
    url: apiURL,
    type: "GET",
    dataType: 'json'});
  success: function (response) {
            // The request succeeded
            console.log(response);
            parseWord(response);

        },
        error: function (xhr, status) {
            // The request failed
            console.log(status);

            showError();
        }

function parseWord(data) {

$('#syno').text(noun.ant);
}

</script>
```

Comment: what is noun?  Where is parseWord called?

Comment: copy that data in the raw text format and save it as a `.json` or use `jQuery.parseJSON( data )`

Comment: noun is a category in the json response

Comment: Add `success: parseWord` to your AJAX config object and make it `.text(data.noun.ant)`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to return the response from an Ajax call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call)

Comment: You have to provide a `success` handler to `ajax` call and use the response there. Mind the cross-domain restriction on `json` requests - http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The function `parseWord(data)` never gets called. If you want `parseWord(data)` to run if the ajax request is successful, you have to do something like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: apiURL,
    type: "GET",
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function parseWord(data) {
               $('#syno').text(data.noun.ant);
             }
});
```

I would suggest you take a look at the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) on this

Comment: The problem is his callback isn't using the argument `data` at all. It should be `data.noun.ant`

Comment: @BrendanScarvell He updated his question before right before i responded, but yes you are correct. See my updated answer.